# How to make an image clickable

Tags: html, css, image, svg, clickable-image

**Hello,**
I would like to make 2 of my images clickable:
The one in my header (Kurium Header Logo)
And the one in my footer (Kurium Footer Logo)

**Here is my code:**

**HTML :** https://bin.readthedocs.fr/ttilty.txt

**CSS :** https://bin.readthedocs.fr/ladvic.txt

If someone knows how I can do it please I'm interested

Comment: U can just create a button but in the content you can pass the image thats this simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn any `element` into a `hyper link` you can wrap your `element` or `string` in between the `a` anchor tag element, inside the first `a` opening tag add an `attribute` `href` to the `url` you desire. Like so

```
<a href="www.url.com">  
    <img src={img.png} />
</a>
```

For a more detailed explanation check out

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help, your method is shorter I keep it aside it can be cool too :p

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap an anchor around them

```
<a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Kurium Header Logo" href="index.html"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand better now how to do it